# Adding datediff results to a new column

Tags: sql

I can easily use the datediff function to get the results between 2 date and time values as number of hours but how do I put this into a new column beside the second date/time column with a custom name along the lines of HoursTrained?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about add column and then update table?

Comment: Adding a column but only to the query result but not updating or modifying the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I don't miss something, then I thik you are looking for something like:

```
Select DateFrom, DateTo, 
       DateDiff(day, DateFrom, DateTo) as 'Difference in Days',
       DateDiff(hour,DateFrom, DateTo) as 'Difference in Hours'
From TableName
```

Comment: Awesome that did the trick! Is there a way of then creating some kind of total row and counting all the results from those datediff columns?